# checking to see if the line in text file falls on specific date and in time range

Tags: python

I have a sample file like below

```
"2021/01/21_23:19:12" "Failure message ssh2"
"2021/01/21_19:26:05" "failure message  ssh2"
"2021/01/21_21:28:09" "failure message ssh2"
"2021/01/22_06:08:04" "failure message ssh2"
"2021/01/22_07:15:03" "failure message ssh2"
```

I am trying to print a failure message which falls in on a specific date and in a time range. was trying to do a regex to pick the date and also the time and compare it.

```
for date in file_content1:
    r1 = re.findall(r"(2021\W\d.\W\d.\S\d.\W\d.\W\d.)", date)
    #if "ze" not in date and "zn" not in date and "zj" not in date and "zi" not in date:
    timing += r1

print(timing)

hour_limit1 = [18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
hour_limit2 = ['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06']

#print(hour_limit1)
#print(hour_limit2)

hour_time = []
for hour in file_content1:
    r5 = re.findall(r"2021\W\d.\W\d.\S(\d.)\W\d.\W\d.", hour)
    #if "ze" not in hour and "zn" not in hour and "zj" not in hour and "zi" not in hour:
    
    hour_time += r5
    
print(hour_time)
r3 = re.findall(r"(2021\W\d.\W\d.)", str(file_content1))
#print(r3)
check_time = []

for day in range(len(file_content1)):
    r3 = re.findall(r"(2021\W\d.\W\d.)", str(file_content1))
    if yesterday1 in file_content1[day]:
        r6 = re.findall(r"2021\W\d.\W\d.\S(\d.)\W\d.\W\d.", str(day))
        print(r6)
```

but doesnot seem to work

Comment: Can you provide an example of your desired output?

Comment: basically trying to get the failure messages which start from 2021/01/21_18:00 to next day 2021/01/22_07:00, so it should print alll message between that range i.e  and not the last line which is after 07:00 next day.
trying to make the starting day as yesterday and end date as today 7:00

 "2021/01/21_23:19:12" "Failure message ssh2" 
"2021/01/21_19:26:05" "failure message ssh2" 
"2021/01/21_21:28:09" "failure message ssh2" 
"2021/01/22_06:08:04" "failure message ssh2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely don't use regex for times and dates in python, instead use `datetime`:

I created a quick example that prints whether a date time is in range within the desired time frame. I got the format codes for datetime strings from here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

```
import datetime

# Print error when on 10th of June, between 7:12am and 9pm

dt_strings = ['2021-06-10 07:12', '2021-06-10 07:13', '2021-06-10 20:59', '2021-06-10 21:00', '2021-06-11 12:00']

start = datetime.time(7, 12)
end = datetime.time(21)
date = datetime.date(2021, 6, 10)
for n, dt_str in enumerate(dt_strings):
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') # 'YEAR-MONTH-DAY HOUR:MINUTE'
    s = str(dt_str)
    if dt.date() == date and dt.time() > start and dt.time() < end:
        s += " is in range"
    else:
        s += " is not in range"
    print(s)
```

Comment: Thank you,  i tried it with the datetime method with range methods you suggested above and did it with some formatting and it worked.